# Setting directives in Vagrant (and ProcessWire)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vagrant, processwire

I'm having a problem where it seems like my Vagrant VirtualBox isn't reading the .htaccess file for a site I have mapped out. (a [proccesswire](http://processwire.com) site)
I've don't know enough about Vagrant to find where I should be editing the directives so that my .htaccess file will be read. As far as I've gathered from searching I need to set a directive like so:

```
<Directory /var/www>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

It seems the primary offender is the AllowOverride is typically set to "None" and needs to be "All". But I have put this in a httpd.conf file in apache and I'm guessing that isn't correct.

A bit more information: When I installed PW in the site root I got this error: " Unable to determine if Apache mod_rewrite (required by ProcessWire) is installed. ". As a result when I try to access a part of the CMS, that is usually handled by rewrite rules, the url (/admin or /processwire by default) just reroutes me to the homepage.

Also, I can delete everything in .htacess or add garbage to it and no errors occur. This tells me that .htacess isn't even being read.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: Mike, No sir. I'm currently using MAMP for my PW projects and Vagrant for everything else.